# Grab Ruby on Rails files and install on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

general question that can be used in many different situations, so I thought it would be interesting to ask.

I'm semi new to Ruby and am learning from Treehouse. I am doing the social media site project, and am about half way through.

I was hoping to set up a separate installation from the source files they give you, of the completed site, to do a simple compare and contrast, and really I am just curious as to what the final product is gonna be like.

My question is, is there an easy way to just grab their files, install all the gems and dependencies and run the rails server. If I just try to run the server on the folder, I get a bunch of errors about Gems not being installed and such, which is expected.

If anyone has a process they use when doing things like migrated entire environments from one location to another, it would be appreciated!

Comment: You should use bundle install in project folder to load all dependencies. Then rake db:migrate for db migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to project directory.
2. Install all of the required Gems by executing

   `bundle install`
3. Create database by executing

   `rake db:create`
4. Then migrate the database by executing

   `rake db:migrate`
5. And finally run the application using

   `rails s`

Comment: Thank you! This was a big help!

Comment: Note to anyone on mountain lion on OSx, make sure you download the newest Command Line Tools from XCode, or you will get an error on the json gem install.

Answer (score 1):

If you have cloned their repository, or copied the files to a folder, try running

```
bundle install
```

from the command line